# Execute jQuery flip after X seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Struggled with the "css vendor prefixes" but couldn't get it to work on all devices. So now, let's try a jQuery solution called jQuery flip.

It works perfect on trigger: "hover" and "click" but the trigger "manual" needs to be activated via JavaScript according to documentation found here: http://nnattawat.github.io/flip/

So my question: How do I write a javascript to active the flip function after 3 seconds?

CODE:

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
  .card {
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 20px;
  }
  .front, .back {
    border: 2px gray solid;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  .front {
    background-color: #ccc;
  }
  .back {
    background-color: red;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="card-1" class="card">
  <div class="front">
      Front: Cursus aliquet mus et sociis, placerat adipiscing a placerat magnis integer nisi lacus in, turpis porttitor? Lectus nunc dis in porta, montes lacus. Tortor. Pid sit nisi eu nec aenean.
  </div>
  <div class="back">
      <a href="http://google.com">link</a>
      Back: Dolor scelerisque ridiculus! Mus? Augue, montes, montes proin rhoncus vel a parturient dapibus eros? Penatibus nascetur. In turpis nisi elementum nascetur habitasse augue egestas, in ac rhoncus odio porttitor turpis.
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  // $(".card").flip();

  $("#card-1").flip({
    axis: "y", // y or x
    reverse: false, // true and false
    trigger: "manual", // click, hover or manual
    speed: 500
  });
});
</script>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zdapLrbs/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) to achieve this.

```
$(function(){

    $("#card-1").flip({
        axis: "y", // y or x
        reverse: false, // true and false
        trigger: "manual", // click, hover or manual
        speed: 500
    });

    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#card-1").flip(true);
    }, 3000);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
setTimeout(function() { yourFunction(); }, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using timeout for 3 seconds:

```
$(function(){

    $("#card-1").flip({
        axis: "y", // y or x
        reverse: false, // true and false
        trigger: "manual", // click, hover or manual
        speed: 500
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.card').flip();
    },3000);

});
```

Comment: Sorry, but where do I put this. In the same javascript? or in a seperate one. If so. In the <head> or <body>?

Comment: `flip()` accepts a parameter with one of these values : `true` - to flip, `false` -   flip backwards, and `toggle` which toggles between both...

Comment: @MorKadosh: What does that have to do with my answer? Using `flip()` is fine.

Comment: @PaparazzoKid I have fiddled your code and it did not work as expected. Looking at the library docs, I noticed this aspect

Comment: @MorKadosh: I'm not trying to make a working solution, as I'm not familiar with the plugin used, I'm simply showing how the user can call their plugin after 3 seconds, which is exactly what they have asked. However, I still do not underdstand what you are trying to point out to me. I've looked at the documentation and there is nothing wrong with using `flip()` on its own - it it toggles by default. Look for yourself: http://nnattawat.github.io/flip/#How-to-use, it says right there `Then, call jQuery flip() on it: $("#card").flip();`.